# GET Requests are not working in Flask

Tags: python, flask, python-webbrowser

I am not able to pass data in Flask using GET Method.

I testing using web browser and it is showing null

```
from flask import Flask, request
import sqlite3
import json

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def test():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    return json.dumps({'result' : name})

@app.route('/test2')
def test2():
    return json.dumps({'result' : "demo"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.0.2', port=8090, debug=True)
```

When I am running in web browser with URL

1. http://192.168.0.2:8090/test2

It is giving result

```
{"result": "demo"}
```

Which is correct.

2. http://192.168.0.2:8090/test?name=rahul

It is giving result

```
{"result": null}
```

Which should be `{"result": "rahul"}`

Where I am making mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `name = request.args.get('name')`

Because you are testing the API using **web browser URL** you have to use `args`

When you are sending data from **form** you can use `name = request.form.get('name')`